# Date formatted using 'ngbDateParserFormatter' not binding to .net core model class

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am submitting a post request with some values in JSON to .net core api, but my Date value is not binding to .net core model. All the other values which are of type string are binding correctly.

Iam formatting the ngdatepicker date with the code :-

> ```
> var holidayDate = this.ngbDateParserFormatter.format(ngbDate);
> ```

Anyone know the issue?

modelclass:-

```
public class HolidayModel
{
  public DateTime holidayDate { get; set; }
  public string holidayType { get; set; }
  public string holidayDescription { get; set; }
  public string financialYear { get; set; }
}
```

JSON:-

```
financialYear: "2019-2020"
holidayDate: "2019-06-07"
holidayDescription: "dfghdfh"
holidayType: "RH"
```

Comment: Don't format the date...Just send the date object directly.

Comment: or the date format for the culture of .NET Core app must match with your application's date format.

Comment: ngbootstrap return date as an object :-

date= {
day:'',
month:'',
year:''
}

Comment: Date object looks like this - Mon Jun 10 2019 11:45:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Comment: I think that sending the date as string yyyy-MM-dd must be work when you defined as DateTime the date in .NET.